# Calculated column colours

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a list with a column called Client Satisfaction which is a choice field with the following

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

I would like a calculated column to make any number between 1,2,3,4,5,6 red, 7 orange and 8,9,10 green

Here are some of the columns in the list, I would like the change the color of the Satisfaction number as stated above

[image]

What would the calculation be?

Thanks

Comment: where do you want this color code. is it the list view?

Comment: Yes in the list view, I have updated my question with a screenshot, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to use HTML calculate column for this, please have a look at:

[HTML Calculated Column - Client Side Rendering](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2013/06/19/html-calculated-column-client-side-rendering/)

For SharePoint 2013, simplest way is to use Client-Side Rendering (JSLink property).. Please have a look at following samples:

[Client-side rendering (JS Link) code samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a)

Comment: Thanks, the HTML calculated column link took me to about three sites and nothing for SP 2013, the other link for SP 2013 the addin is $900.

Comment: Answer is updated, please have a look.

Comment: I am trying to use this link http://usermanagedsolutions.com/SharePoint-User-Toolkit/Pages/Color-Coding-Calendar-List.aspx but the column once added just says red, it does not display the number at all